When evaluating GLM models, is the AIC value or the p-value of predictor significance more important?
I have generated GLM models (Poisson distribution), now I am trying to interpret the obtained data.
I provide a sample of my data.
Example<-structure(list(birds = c(9L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 
5L, 2L), area = c(3.55, 2.52, 1.49, 1, 1.13, 1.49, 1.4, 0.57, 
1.11, 1.78, 1.63), density = c(2.5, 0.8, 1.3, 4, 0.9, 0.7, 2.9, 
1.8, 4.5, 2.8, 1.2), green = c(5.95, 5.62, 6.32, 6.04, 4.91, 
5.36, 7.15, 5.22, 6.8, 6.69, 6.47), open = c(3.69, 5, 3.94, 4.05, 
3.48, 3.97, 4.12, 4.29, 4.29, 3.56, 4), distance = c(0.6, 3, 
1, 0.9, 1, 1, 2.5, 3.2, 3.8, 2.5, 3), human = c(21.29, 22.76, 
23.02, 20.88, 21.26, 21.87, 23.19, 21.82, 19.49, 21.68, 19.6)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-11L))

fix(Example) # data table

As an example, I give several resulting models.
model.4=glm (birds ~ green + offset(log(area)),
data=Example, family = poisson (link="log"))
summary(model.4)

Call:
glm(formula = birds ~ green + offset(log(area)), family = poisson(link = "log"), 
    data = Example)

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)   
(Intercept)   -5.179      1.785  -2.902  0.00371 **
green          0.581      0.283   2.053  0.04008 * 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for poisson family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 11.5277  on 10  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance:  7.1937  on  9  degrees of freedom
AIC: 42.581

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 4

model.3=glm (birds ~ green + human + offset(log(area)),
data=Example, family = poisson (link="log"))
summary(model.3)

Call:
glm(formula = birds ~ green + human + offset(log(area)), family = poisson(link = "log"), 
    data = Example)

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)  
(Intercept)  -2.2270     3.4786  -0.640   0.5220  
green         0.5700     0.2929   1.946   0.0516 .
human        -0.1342     0.1308  -1.026   0.3049  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for poisson family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 11.5277  on 10  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance:  6.1475  on  8  degrees of freedom
AIC: 43.535

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 4

model.2=glm (birds ~ green + human + distance + offset(log(area)),
data=Example, family = poisson (link="log"))
summary(model.2)
Call:
glm(formula = birds ~ green + human + distance + offset(log(area)), 
    family = poisson(link = "log"), data = Example)

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)  
(Intercept)  -1.8965     3.5104  -0.540   0.5890  
green         0.7951     0.3795   2.095   0.0362 *
human        -0.1954     0.1477  -1.322   0.1861  
distance     -0.2163     0.1942  -1.114   0.2652  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for poisson family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 11.5277  on 10  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance:  4.8388  on  7  degrees of freedom
AIC: 44.226

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 4

model.8=glm (birds ~ open + offset(log(area)),
data=Example, family = poisson (link="log"))
summary(model.8)

Call:
glm(formula = birds ~ open + offset(log(area)), family = poisson(link = "log"), 
    data = Example)

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept)  -0.1216     1.6031  -0.076    0.940
open         -0.3674     0.4021  -0.914    0.361

(Dispersion parameter for poisson family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 11.528  on 10  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 10.637  on  9  degrees of freedom
AIC: 46.024

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 5

In the three models presented above (model.4, model.3, model.2), the p-values of the predictors are statistically significant (or close to significance) only in relation to the predictor "green", the other predictors ("human", "distance") included in the models turned out to be not statistically significant. In one model (model.8), only one predictor ("open") is included, which is not statistically significant.
How to interpret such models containing not statistically significant predictors? Take into account only the AIC(AICc) value and ignore the not statistical significant of the predictors? Or not?
For a more complete picture, I present the remaining 11 models below.
model.1=glm (birds ~ green + human + distance + open + offset(log(area)),
data=Example, family = poisson (link="log"))
summary(model.final)
Call:
glm(formula = birds ~ green + human + distance + open + offset(log(area)), 
    family = poisson(link = "log"), data = Example)

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)  
(Intercept)  -2.4069     4.0876  -0.589   0.5560  
green         0.8450     0.4337   1.948   0.0514 .
human        -0.2125     0.1627  -1.307   0.1913  
distance     -0.2628     0.2716  -0.968   0.3333  
open          0.1652     0.6764   0.244   0.8071  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for poisson family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 11.5277  on 10  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance:  4.7785  on  6  degrees of freedom
AIC: 46.166

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 4

model.5=glm (birds ~ human + offset(log(area)),
data=Example, family = poisson (link="log"))
summary(model.5)
Call:
glm(formula = birds ~ human + offset(log(area)), family = poisson(link = "log"), 
    data = Example)

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept)   2.2068     3.0565   0.722    0.470
human        -0.1767     0.1428  -1.238    0.216

(Dispersion parameter for poisson family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 11.528  on 10  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 10.025  on  9  degrees of freedom
AIC: 45.412

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 4


model.6=glm (birds ~ distance + offset(log(area)),
data=Example, family = poisson (link="log"))
summary(model.6)

Call:
glm(formula = birds ~ distance + offset(log(area)), family = poisson(link = "log"), 
    data = Example)

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept) -1.64705    0.33643  -4.896  9.8e-07 ***
distance     0.02925    0.15095   0.194    0.846    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for poisson family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 11.528  on 10  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 11.490  on  9  degrees of freedom
AIC: 46.878

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 5

model.7=glm (birds ~ human + distance + offset(log(area)),
data=Example, family = poisson (link="log"))
summary(model.7)

Call:
glm(formula = birds ~ human + distance + offset(log(area)), family = poisson(link = "log"), 
    data = Example)

Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept)  2.281603   3.284113   0.695    0.487
human       -0.179327   0.149100  -1.203    0.229
distance    -0.009678   0.151668  -0.064    0.949

(Dispersion parameter for poisson family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 11.528  on 10  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 10.021  on  8  degrees of freedom
AIC: 47.408

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 4
model.9=glm (birds ~ green + open + offset(log(area)),
data=Example, family = poisson (link="log"))
summary(model.9)

Call:
glm(formula = birds ~ green + open + offset(log(area)), family = poisson(link = "log"), 
    data = Example)

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)  
(Intercept)  -3.7298     2.5592  -1.457   0.1450  
green         0.5624     0.2848   1.975   0.0483 *
open         -0.3340     0.4410  -0.757   0.4488  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for poisson family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 11.5277  on 10  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance:  6.5917  on  8  degrees of freedom
AIC: 43.979

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 4

model.10=glm (birds ~ green + distance + offset(log(area)),
data=Example, family = poisson (link="log"))
summary(model.10)

Call:
glm(formula = birds ~ green + distance + offset(log(area)), family = poisson(link = "log"), 
    data = Example)

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)   
(Intercept)  -5.6195     1.9287  -2.914  0.00357 **
green         0.6923     0.3284   2.108  0.03501 * 
distance     -0.1295     0.1757  -0.737  0.46108   
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for poisson family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 11.5277  on 10  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance:  6.6395  on  8  degrees of freedom
AIC: 44.027

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 4

model.11=glm (birds ~ open + distance + offset(log(area)),
data=Example, family = poisson (link="log"))
summary(model.11)

Call:
glm(formula = birds ~ open + distance + offset(log(area)), family = poisson(link = "log"), 
    data = Example)

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept)   0.5110     1.7469   0.293    0.770
open         -0.6039     0.4792  -1.260    0.208
distance      0.1636     0.1801   0.908    0.364

(Dispersion parameter for poisson family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 11.5277  on 10  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance:  9.8245  on  8  degrees of freedom
AIC: 47.212

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 5

model.12=glm (birds ~ open + human + offset(log(area)),
data=Example, family = poisson (link="log"))
summary(model.12)

Call:
glm(formula = birds ~ open + human + offset(log(area)), family = poisson(link = "log"), 
    data = Example)

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept)   2.8674     3.3452   0.857    0.391
open         -0.2740     0.4215  -0.650    0.516
human        -0.1565     0.1503  -1.041    0.298

(Dispersion parameter for poisson family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 11.5277  on 10  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance:  9.5874  on  8  degrees of freedom
AIC: 46.975

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 5

model.13=glm (birds ~ green + open + distance + offset(log(area)),
data=Example, family = poisson (link="log"))
summary(model.13)

Call:
glm(formula = birds ~ green + open + distance + offset(log(area)), 
    family = poisson(link = "log"), data = Example)

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)  
(Intercept) -4.47615    3.42910  -1.305   0.1918  
green        0.63408    0.35959   1.763   0.0778 .
open        -0.22261    0.55847  -0.399   0.6902  
distance    -0.07427    0.22352  -0.332   0.7397  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for poisson family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 11.5277  on 10  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance:  6.4807  on  7  degrees of freedom
AIC: 45.868

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 4

model.14=glm (birds ~ green + open + human + offset(log(area)),
data=Example, family = poisson (link="log"))
summary(model.14)



Call:
glm(formula = birds ~ green + open + human + offset(log(area)), 
    family = poisson(link = "log"), data = Example)

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)  
(Intercept)  -1.2418     3.8194  -0.325    0.745  
green         0.5638     0.2926   1.927    0.054 .
open         -0.2845     0.4541  -0.626    0.531  
human        -0.1255     0.1349  -0.930    0.352  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for poisson family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 11.5277  on 10  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance:  5.7405  on  7  degrees of freedom
AIC: 45.128

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 4

model.15=glm (birds ~ open + distance  + human + offset(log(area)),
data=Example, family = poisson (link="log"))
summary(model.15)

Call:
glm(formula = birds ~ open + distance + human + offset(log(area)), 
    family = poisson(link = "log"), data = Example)

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept)   2.5216     3.3832   0.745    0.456
open         -0.4516     0.5425  -0.832    0.405
distance      0.1016     0.2006   0.506    0.613
human        -0.1164     0.1667  -0.698    0.485

(Dispersion parameter for poisson family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 11.5277  on 10  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance:  9.3329  on  7  degrees of freedom
AIC: 48.72

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 5
```


It might help if you edited to state your scientific question.

I edited the text.

For your specific case, the only interesting model is model.4 and whether you compare p-values or AIC doesn't matter. Ot has both the lowest AIC and a low p-value for a t-test on it's parameter. Btw, these p-values are for specific model comparisons where we drop a songle value. E.g. the 0.0516 p-value for 'green' in model.3 is not for a comparison with model.4 but for a comparison with model.6

Sextus Empiricus, thanks for the comments. But it turns out that
the lowest p-value is not in model 4 (p=0.04008), but in model 2 (p=0.0362).

AIC and p-values

is the AIC value or the p-value of predictor significance more important?

They are expressing the same thing: "whether or not a certain model is well supported by the data or not".
For a comparison with 1 degree of freedom difference, a zero AIC difference corresponds roughly to a p-value significance cutoff of 0.157 for the smaller model as hypothesis (both p-values and AIC are derived from the same statistic, a comparison between log-likelihhod).

P-values put more stress on one particular model. They estimate the probability of the data given that particular model.
It is used in  hypothesis testing and settings of 'extraordinary claims require extraordinary evidence' by placing low p-value boundaries on the required proof to lower the rate of false positives (false rejection).
Typical levels are 0.05 or smaller (and reach up to extremes like several sigmas) and that is more stringent than the 0.157 which correspondends to a decision based on AIC.

Comparisons based on AIC place more stress on an equal comparison of two models. It estimates the difference between the models and the true data generating process.
The situation here is that, a priori, no model is preferred over one another and we want to select a model based on new information from data. The model whose estimated difference with the true process is the one that will be selected.



For your specific case
The only interesting model is model.4
Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)  
(Intercept)   -5.179      1.785  -2.902  0.00371 **
green          0.581      0.283   2.053  0.04008  

It has both the lowest AIC value (42.581) and a low p-value for a t-test on all it's parameters. So, whether you compare p-values or AIC doesn't matter. The difference is large with all the other models.
Btw, these p-values for specific factors are occasionally low in the other models. But that is for specific model comparisons where we drop a single value and not for the entire model. If you have at least one of the p-values above 0.157, to then it means that the model doesn't have the lowest AIC value (namely the model where the parameter with p-value above 0.157 is removed will have a lower AIC value).
For example take the model.3
Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)  
(Intercept)  -2.2270     3.4786  -0.640   0.5220  
green         0.5700     0.2929   1.946   0.0516 .
human        -0.1342     0.1308  -1.026   0.3049  

It has a reasonable low 0.0516 p-value for 'green' but that is not for a comparison with model.4 and instead for a comparison with model.5 where the only factor is human (without green).
Nuance about AIC comparisons
The AIC values are estimates for the goodness of fit of the models. In your case with only 11 data points these estimates can be inaccurate and you can likely choose a model that is not truly the best.
If you look at the range for parameter estimates then you can see better whether the insignificance of the model estimates is because the error is very large or because the value is close to zero. For example the model.3 estimate for the 'human' coefficient is $-0.1342$ and with a standard error of $0.1308$ not significantly different from zero. But if you care about effect sizes of smaller order, then this means that it is not like you observed a small effect, and isntead it is like you just had a too large error in your estimate to tell the difference accurately enough.

Here is my advice. Set statistical significance to the side for the time being and look at the big picture.
Your first objective is to hopefully tell a story about why these models are theoretically important. I only comment on the four models you have here, but it appears you mention there being eight models in total, so I will only comment on what is here. You seem to have a sort of baseline model with just "green" included. Its not clear what this means wrt to your research, but we can see it has some positive association. Why? Is this model meaningful on it's own? Great. Then we have some kind of answer for your theory, but I assume the additional models are supposed to rule out some important factors that may modify the importance of this single variable. Note here that by itself, a one unit increase in "green" yields something approximate to a $78.8\%$ increase in the number of birds. This is approximated by exponentiating the coefficients and subtracting by 1:
> exp(.581) - 1
[1] 0.7878254

So it seems that whatever green is, it seems on the surface that this may be important for predicting how many birds there are. Why that is the case is, again, a theoretical explanation / story you need to be able to tell, rather than will the explanation into existence based off data alone.
Your second model in your output just below the green-only model, the one that just adds humans as a predictor, slightly decreases this impact after controlling for humans (where it appears that humans have a negative influence on the presence of birds). When $\text{Humans = 0}$, this yields an approximate $76.8\%$ increase in the number of birds for every one unit increase in green. While the $p$ value is nudged out of the conventional $.05$ cutoffs, I don't find this to actually be a meaningful distinction, but I'm a neo-Fisherian (re: I treat $p$ values as continuous), so my perspective on this is different from the standard Fisher-Neyman-Pearson NHST paradigm of $p$ value hypothesis testing. Regardless, green seems to still have an impact, but when $p$ values are too large, some may say that the generated effects may be simply chance. Follow-up research can perhaps determine if this effect is "real" or not, but that is not under your control for this specific analysis. Why this may be the case depends on past research in your field and the theory that supports the idea that the joint contribution of human presence and whatever green is predicts bird counts.
The next model adds distance, which seems to also have a negative association. However, the more important takeaway is that adding in distance changes the predicted effect of green by a lot now:
> exp(0.7951) - 1
[1] 1.214662

We now have a $121.4\%$ increase in bird counts for every one unit increase in green, holding human and distance at zero. Unsurprisingly, the $p$ value decreases, though again not by some extreme amount. To quantify this in more directly tangible terms, I have calculated the $s$ values for this change (more on those here):
> -log2( 0.0516)
[1] 4.276485
> -log2( 0.0362)
[1] 4.787866

Basically, the first model says something like the conditional effect of green  is as likely to be found as getting $4.276$ coin heads in a row on coin flips, whereas the competing model is akin to about $4.788$ heads in a row. This isn't really that meaningful of a difference in my opinion, and is partly why the magical $.05$ cutoff is silly when you consider the distance between values around this cutoff (it also isn't always a great determinant of practical significance, hence my examination of the coefficients here). The last model has no relation to the others and must have some competing interest from a theoretical perspective to be comparable in any way, but it's not clear why that model matters here when the others are more relatable.
As for how to compare these models, it is common to use either AIC/BIC values (which are simply continuous measures based on the likelihood) or $p$ value-based determinations like likelihood ratio tests (LRTs). This is more a philosophical difference which is up to the user. I personally am allergic to determining anything based off $p$ values alone, so I would use a combination of AIC/BIC values and logic about where that theoretical model places itself in terms of importance and predictive power.
Most importantly, do not ignore terms in your model simply because they are statistically non-significant. It is important for others to know which predictors matter and which don't. The predictions of your model are also meaningless if you omit them from the linear equation. So leave all the models you tested in, report your interpretations of them, and provide the data for others to determine if you are right or not.

Shawn Hemelstrand, thank you for the detailed explanations and comments, they will be very useful. From a biological point of view, I expected to register a positive relationship between "green" (an indicator of the area of green spaces) and the number of birds. The "human" and "distance" indicators assess the intensity of the anthropogenic factor, an increase in these indicators can lead to a decrease in the number of birds, but this is still at the level of an assumption. I have 15 models in total. Just in case, in my question I have now given the remaining 11 models.

Why do you have so many models to begin with? I would be very careful with testing so many models unless you have really good reasons for it. It can increase the likelihood of chance discoveries, and there should at least be some theory explaining why such models should be tested. This is particularly true if you include many "control" variables that don't actually have a relationship between the predictor and outcome.

Shawn Hemelstrand, thanks for your comments. I am planning to test several models (about 5-7) with the lowest AIC/BIC values. I have a follow-up question on your answer. You compared three models using exp. In the third model (green + human + distance) the exp value for "green" was the highest (121.4%) compared to the other two models (78.8 and 76.8%). Could this be one of the arguments that the model with the higher exp value for "green" is more successful than the other two models?

In principle, yes, but again it has to make sense from a theoretical perspective. It could be totally spurious given that any variable inclusion can create a non-zero change in the weight of each predictor. Therefore one must understand why, in the face of distance and humans, the effect would be more profound for green spaces in such a model. It is also important that these theoretical explanations should be considered before a model is fit, rather than fitting a bunch of models and giving post-hoc explanations.
